# Correct ReST URI design

Tags: rest

I have the following (hypothetical) scenario:

Application to report on students in classes in schools.  I have 3 tables school, class, student.  Class has a FK school_id and student has a FK class_id.

I have my Entities all set up and ready to go and I am about to expose them via a Rest interface.

Should my URIs look like this:
Schools - list of schools
Schools/{id} - specific school
Schools/{id}/classes - list of classes
Schools/{id}/classes/{id} - specific class
Schools/{id}/classes/{id}/student - list students
Schools/{id}/classes/{id}/student/{id} - specific students

Even though in the case of specific student I will be ignoring the I will be ignoring the school id and the class id as all I care about for my query is the student id.

Should I just have:
Schools/student/{id} - for specific students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with exposing a resource from multiple locations (though it's a good idea to specify the [canonical url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) if there are multiple locations*).

Thus it may make sense to provide all the following URIs:

```
lists:

student
classes/{id}/student
schools/{id}/classes/{id}/student

specific:

student/{id}
classes/{id}/student/{id}
schools/{id}/classes/{id}/student/{id}
```

In your case the relationship between entities is not an entity itself. If this were the case (eg. if you had the resource class-student with an attribute specifying how long the student had been in the class) then the URIs that include both `class` and `student` ids become more important as they provide a good place to expose the attributes of the relationship itself.

*to best provide the canonical url to the client you can send it as the value of the "Content-Location" in the response headers.

Comment: For the lists section, would the value of the student list be a list of URI's referencing the canonical location for each specific student in the list?

Comment: +1 because of the reference to adding the canonical url to the content-location.  Good tip.

Comment: @ScottCher, I don't think it matters, but personally in the page content I would use links that just add the student ID to the current URL. That way the URL context serves as a  simple "breadcrumbs" feature.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it is useful to have a convention for using plural/singular names.
Some people like only singular names, some (like Ruby folks) using both and a conversion tool.
For example, in Ian's answer `student` list URL must be `students`.

Comment: I agree this is important - though also a source of controversy! I prefer singular everywhere for resources because I work in multilingual environments and plurals in other languages can be much more complex than in English, but in my answer I follow the examples in the question.

Comment: Interesting, I would prefer plural everywhere when the result could be a collection (0-many).  then /classes/{id}/students makes more send and so does /classes/{id}/students{id}.  I get what you are saying about it being controversial and multilingual environments.  What's that old saying about standards being magical because there are so many of them?  8)